# AND "not working" in mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT: This turned out to be a test data mis-match. Some people have found the discussions below useful.

```
"SELECT tran_id, person_id, month_week FROM tran_to_time 
WHERE month_week = :month_week AND send_time = :nowTime;";// 
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':month_week',$nowWeek, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':nowTime',$nowTime, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
$result=$statement ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

This was working fine (I think).

Using dummy data of time = 1111 and month week = 3 things are as follows.

If I remove either side of the `AND` it works fine. IE if I do `WHERE month_week = :month_week` or I do `WHERE send_time = :nowTime` I get an array of results in `$result`. If I use the AND `$result` is empty. I tried using () but to no avail.

TIA for any thoughts.

Comment: Why you have a `;` in your SQL Statement? typo?

Comment: haha +1 just for your name BeNice lol

Comment: The `;` doesn't (and shouldn't) make any difference. It is just there as a separator between SQL statements. (The problem was user error - ie I had entered week 4 instead of 3 - d'oh!).

And John thanks for that :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I use the AND $result is empty

Other than the typo `;` in your query; if the `AND` condition returning empty result set then for sure your `WHERE` condition is `FLASE`. Means the below condition is not matching any row

```
WHERE month_week = :month_week AND send_time = :nowTime
```

Comment: Oh lord - thanks Rahul. I thought I had plenty of "Sunday, 1111, week 3"s.... but I managed to make them week 4. Only excuse exhaustion and terminal stupidity.

Answer (score 2):

As @Rizier123 pointed out, you have a typo.

```
WHERE month_week = :month_week AND send_time = :nowTime";//
```

instead of

```
WHERE month_week = :month_week AND send_time = :nowTime;";//
```